# Android startActivityForResult createChooser всегда RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-intent

мучаюсь с проблемой: хочу использовать `Intent.ACTION_SEND` для отправки сообщения через почтовый(или другой) клиент с возможностью выбора самого клиента.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("plain/text");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{
      "my_mail@gmail.com"
});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TEST");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , text);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."), 111);
```

но в `onActivityResult` мне всегда возвращает только `RESULT_CANCELED`, что при отмене, что при отправке...

Собственно это знание позволит мне после успешной отправки закрыть страничку где формировалось письмо на моей стороне, или же оставить возможность вносить правки если человек передумал...

Может кто-то знает как мне выкрутиться, буду благодарен!)

Comment: Похоже, никак https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778048/how-can-we-use-startactivityforresult-for-email-intent

Comment: Jarvis_J, да, я уже переглил все что возможно, может я кардинально не так делаю, может кто придумал как бы по другому выполнить ту же задачу...))

Comment: Будет полезно узнать, если так)